# simple way to run a python program under ROS

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I run a simple Python program under ROS (turtlebot is already running)?
How do I launch (start?) it?

Alan  KM6VV

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58072/simple-way-to-run-a-python-program-under-ros/) by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-03-13**:
could you please explain some thing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Put the files in a folder and then add the folder to your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Then chmod a+x your_program.py

---

Originally posted by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) with karma: 229 on 2013-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1